# C++ how to change value of a map element

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map with an integer and a class I made. Now I need to change the integer of each element in the list.

I thought about sth like this :

```
std::map<int, Product> ProductList; //This is filled somewhere and can be accessed in my function 

void remove()
{
  std::map<int, Product>::iterator it = ProductList.begin();
  for(; it != ProductList.end(); it++)
  {
    it->first = it->first - 1;
  }
}
```

Now my compiler says

> error: assignment of read-only member '`std::pair<const int, Product>::first`'

What am I doing wrong? I need to subtract `1` from the integer of each element.

Comment: did you tried using *(it).first?

Comment: Didn't work. Also I don't understand why this would make any difference.

Comment: It looks like you want the int to be the index of the class in the map -> Just use Vector instead.

Comment: I thougt that by doing that you can modify directly the memory location for key.

Comment: Astro, value_type in map containers is an alias of std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>, so unless you do something crazy like const_cast it, you can't modify the key (nor should you, the map would not update it's internal data structure, and you would get undefined behavior).

Comment: keys of a map can not be changed (would you like it if someone changes the key to your house while you are out?)... :) you can however achieve what you want by creating a new map and initializing that with key values as you like

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the keys of the map like that; the map would have to reorder the elements internally, so you should create a new map and swap it with the old one.

```
void remove()
{
   typedef std::map<int, Product> ProductMap;

   ProductMap shifted;
   ProductMap::const_iterator it  = ProductList.begin();
   ProductMap::const_iterator end = ProductList.end();

   for(; it != end; ++it)
      shifted.insert(std::pair<int, Product>(it->first - 1, it->second));

   ProductList.swap(shifted);
}
```

Comment: Compiler says missing template arguments before '(' token in the line where shifted inserts the new pair. I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You are trying to modify the key of an element in the map. The key unlocks the value, so the value is unlocked by the key. How can you unlock the same value with a different key?

You are using a map, because it is easy to get the value by the key. But you are trying to use the key as an index, which is not possible, this is a different data structure.

I think you should use a vector for your elements, or a vector for your keys, or a temporary copy of the map. If you give me more information about why are you trying to do this, then maybe I can be more specific about the solution too.

Comment: Well there has to be a product and an index. When the user clicks on previous or next it should go to that product. But whenever the user wants to remove a product all indexes should be decremented by one. The user should also be able to add a new product. I think a list would be better than a map or a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a new pair into the map, and erase the old one.  It's probably best just to create a new map:

```
std::map<int,Product> oldProductList;
std::map<int,Product> newProductList;
std::map<product,int>::iterator it = iksProductList.begin();
for(; it != ProductList.end(); it++)
{
    newProductList[it->first - 1] = it->second;
}
```

Comment: So I have to erase everything and inser it again just to subtract the integer by 1 ?

Comment: You not "subtract[ing] the integer by one," you're trying to "change the key in a key-value pair in a map" and you can't do that!   Not through the iterator.

Comment: Don't use map[...] like this; you are default-constructing a Product and then using the copy constructor.  It's faster to use map.insert(...)